# jQuery Datatables get first displayed row custom attribute

Tags: javascript, datatables

I need to get the first displayed row value of `data-rowNum` attribute when next page event if fired.

My HTML table:

```
<tr data-rowNum="1">Some text</tr>
<tr data-rowNum="2">Some text</tr>
<tr data-rowNum="3">Some text</tr>
```

Here is the code I use, but not getting the value, only an object.

```
$('#historico').on( 'page.dt search.dt order.dt', function () {
  alert(tabla.row( 0 ).data('rowNum'));
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [row().node()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.node%28%29) to get the row `TR` node and [to$()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/to%24()) to convert it to jQuery object.

Argument `{ 'order': 'current', 'search': 'applied', 'page': 'current'}` which is [selector-modifier](http://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) for [row()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29) API function is used to retrieve row for current page with sorting and filtering applied.

```
$('#historico').on( 'page.dt search.dt order.dt', function () {
    alert(
       tabla
          .row( 0, { 'order': 'current', 'search': 'applied', 'page': 'current'} )
          .node()
          .to$()
          .data('rowNum'));
});
```

Comment: Thnx Gycocode! Now i can access the first row custom data! Is it possible to access the current page first element? Now it's getting the whole table first element.

Comment: @SauronZ, added more details per your suggestion.

Comment: Thnx again. You opened to me a new world of posibilities. :-)